# Rasterio reading outshape resample does not give correct array

Tags: python, rasterio, resampling

I have a population grid and want to decrease the resolution by a factor 2.  I would like to get a raster that has 2 times less rows and columns, a resolution that is 2 times as large as the original one, while retaining the same number of population.

This should be a straightforward operation, but the population numbers change incorrectly if I follow the [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html). When the resampled array is written to file, the numbers are incorrect.

```
import rasterio 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
 
 
factor = 2

with rasterio.open("mwi_ppp_2020.tif") as dataset:
    
    arr = dataset.read(1,masked=True)
    #Show total population of Malawi 
    print(arr.sum())

    data = dataset.read(1, masked=True,resampling=Resampling.bilinear,
        out_shape=(
            int(dataset.height * factor),
            int(dataset.width * factor)))

     #Show total population of array 
    print(data.sum())

     # scale image transform
    transform = dataset.transform * dataset.transform.scale(
            (dataset.width / data.shape[1]),
            (dataset.height / data.shape[0])
                                )
```

[image]

Shouldn't the resample method yield an array with resampled cell values to get the same number of total population?

Comment: I don't think so?  Looks like you're increasing the total number of pixels then you're summing all of their values.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Thanks mikewatt. I would like to get raster that has 2 times less rows and columns, a resolution that is 2 times as large as the original one, while retaining the same number of population

Comment: I was asking more why you want lower resolution data instead of using the raster as-is.  But using "sum" as the resampling method might get you close:
 https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.enums.html#rasterio.enums.Resampling

Comment: The numbers will be correct for the specified resampling algorithm (bilinear interpolation), however they're not what you are wanting. I suspect you want to sum which is only available if your rasterio is using a very recent GDAL (>= 3.1).  An alternative is the [scikit `block_reduce`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html?#block-reduce) function.

Comment: thank you so much for your replies! I solved the problem by both using a newer version of gdal and alternatively using  scikit block_reduce

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using help in the comments. I needed gdal>3.1 for the sum aggregation/interpolation method (bilinear is wrong in this case).

The gdal code is

```
gdalwarp -tr 0.0083 0.0083 -r sum  -srcnodata -9999 -dstnodata -9999 mwi_ppp_2020.tif  outtest.tif
```

scikit block_reduce was also working as alternative (with factor 10 in this example), but you have to very **careful** with the **nodata entries** and the **affine transform**. So gdalwarp is the better alternative.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If gdal is used, then it's also possible to use the gdal python bindings.

```
from osgeo import gdal

# Input and output file paths
input_file = "mwi_ppp_2020.tif"
output_file = "outtest.tif"

# Resampling method
resample_alg = "sum"

# Warp options
options = gdal.WarpOptions(
    format="GTiff",
    xRes=0.0083,
    yRes=0.0083,
    srcNodata=-9999,
    dstNodata=-9999,
    resampleAlg=resample_alg
    )

# Perform the warp operation
gdal.Warp(output_file, input_file, options=options)
```

[gdal.Warp()](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Warp) and [gdal.WarpOptions()](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.WarpOptions) docs.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
int(dataset.height / factor),
int(dataset.width / factor)))
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not work. It reduces the population count to about 4million and does not calculate the correct cell values